# Protractor debugging fails in webstorm

Tags: protractor

Protractor test runs successfully, but fails to debug.

When ever I run the it launch the browser, and the fails.

Debugger listening on port 56547
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.129.19.134:51931/wd/hub

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Any Idea ?

Protractor version is 3.3.2
Selenium is 2.25.2

Answer (score 0):

Yeahs I ran into the same issue and instead started using browser.pause(); in the code to debug

Comment: So you mean I should not use the UI to debug, instead debug on terminal ?